# How to compare date in MS Access database?

Tags: database

My `CheckTime` output format is `8/17/2014 5:45:22 PM`. How I can compare `CheckTime` with `Date()` ?

```
SELECT  c.Userid, c.CheckTime, 'Sign In' AS Action
FROM Checkinout c
WHERE c.CheckType = 'I' AND Format(CheckTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") = Date()
UNION
SELECT  c.Userid, c.CheckTime, 'Sign Out' AS Action
FROM Checkinout c
WHERE c.CheckType = 'O' AND c.CheckTime = Date();
```

Comment: Why are you formatting the checktime in the where statement? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'll want to record the checkouts also? How are you planning to match the check-ins to the corresponding check-outs?

Why not make a table like this instead:

```
 | UserId | CheckInTime | CheckOutTime |
```

Then you could do:

```
SELECT c.Userid, c.CheckInTime, c.CheckOutTime,  
       IIF ( NOT ISNULL(c.CheckOutTime), 
             DateDiff("n",c.CheckTime,c.CheckTime)/60 & "." &          
             DateDiff("n",c.CheckTime,c.CheckTime) Mod 60,
             NULL) as TimeElapsed,
FROM Checkinout c;
```

**Note:** This would get hours and minutes, but you could do something similar to get the days and seconds.

Comment: As far my database and query I wrote avobe When CheckType = 'I', it considered as CheckInTime and when CheckType = 'O' is considered as CheckOutTime so no need to define CheckInTime or CheckOutTime separately. Field CheckTime gives output as "8/17/2014 5:45:22 PM" and Date() function gives output as "8/18/2014" now please, just tell me how I can compare this two value to check these days are same....?

Comment: "DateDiff" is how you compare two dates.